# Multiple urls pointing to a single resource with no redundancy

Tags: url, django-1.7

In django's urls.py I got this:

```
url(r'^main$', 'views.send_partial', name='main'),
url(r'^login$', 'views.send_partial', name='login'),
url(r'^signup$', 'views.send_partial', name='signup'),
url(r'^help$', 'views.send_partial', name='help'),
```

And I hate repeating code, so I would like to get rid of repeating the same function on and on for every url that should be handled by it. I can not find out how this is done anywhere. So what I am expecting is something like:

```
url('views.send_partial',
    r'^main$', name='main,
    r'^login$', name='login',
    r'^signup$', name='signup',
    r'^help$', name='help')
```

Ideas?

Comment: The first thing coming to my mind is a loop.

Comment: @TobiMarg There is a way to do it cleanly, I have seen it some time ago somewhere, but I can find anything like it now. And I can not visualize it with a loop, would you explain further?

Comment: I haven't found anything in the documentation about a better way (I haven't used django a long time), so I added my idea with a loop as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found nothing in the [documentation (django.conf.urls)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urls/), but I think it could be solved with a list/dict of patterns and names.

```
url_dict = {'main': 'r'^main$', 'login': r'^login$',
            'signup': r'^signup$', 'help': r'^help$'}

# This part could also be put into a function taking the 
# dictionary and the handler and returning urlpatterns
urls = []
for name, pattern in url_dict.items():
    urls.append(url(pattern, 'views.send_partial', name=name))
urlpatterns = patterns('', *urls)
```

First you create a dictionary mapping the names to patterns (could also be something like a list of lists). Then you loop through the dictionary, creating a list of urlpatterns using `url()`. Finally you let them trough `patterns()` or do what else you was doing with them.

Comment: It is a valid approach, thank you, I'll still leave it open if someone shows up with a better idea.